# OpenCL potential race on read buffer non blocking

Tags: c, callback, opencl, race-condition

Although it is not important, I have three 3 buffers of the same size, and a sample kernel.cl (just vector addition). I omit the initialization and releasing steps of the execution.

I have two write buffer (buffer A and B) and one kernel execution (shown below). I define 2 callbacks.

```
void
CL_CALLBACK callback_read_fn(cl_event event, cl_int ev_status, void* user_data)
{
  printf("callback read executed (%d)\n", ev_status);
  callback_data* cb_data = (callback_data*)user_data;
  int* c_v = cb_data->c_v;
  cl_event end = *(cb_data->end);

  cl_int st;

  printf("c_v %p\n", (void*)c_v);
  printf("c_v[0] = %d\n", c_v[0]);

  c_v[1] = 1;

  st = clSetUserEventStatus(end, CL_COMPLETE);
  printf("set event callback (%d)\n", st);
}

void
CL_CALLBACK callback_kernel_fn(cl_event event, cl_int ev_status, void* user_data)
{
  printf("callback kernel executed (%d)\n", ev_status);
  callback_data* cb_data = (callback_data*)user_data;
  cl_command_queue queue = *(cb_data->queue);
  cl_mem buf_c = *(cb_data->buf_c);
  int* c_v = cb_data->c_v;
  int size = cb_data->size;
  bool nested_callbacks = cb_data->nested_callbacks;
  bool blocking = cb_data->blocking;
  cl_event end = *(cb_data->end);

  cl_event ev_read;

  printf("c_v %p\n", (void*)c_v);
  printf("c_v[0] = %d\n", c_v[0]);

  cl_int st;

  /* printf("about to flush\n"); */
  /* clFlush(queue); */
  /* printf("flushed\n"); */

  size_t offset = 0;
  /* size = size + 4; */
  printf("about to read the c buffer\n");
  /* why it does not work? -  blocking to CL_TRUE */
  st = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buf_c, blocking, offset,
                           size * sizeof(int), c_v, 0, NULL, &ev_read);
                           /* size * sizeof(int), c_v, 0, NULL, NULL); */


  if (nested_callbacks){
    st = clSetEventCallback(ev_read, CL_COMPLETE, callback_read_fn, user_data);
    printf("set event callback (%d)\n", st);
  }

  if (!nested_callbacks){
    st = clSetUserEventStatus(end, CL_COMPLETE);
    printf("set event callback (%d)\n", st);

    printf("read buffer c_v - buf_c (%d)\n", st);
  }
}

int
main()
{
  // initialization

  // Execute kernel
  st = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, dims, NULL, (const size_t*)gws,
                              (const size_t*)lws, 0, NULL, &ev_kernel);
                              /* (const size_t*)lws, 0, NULL, NULL); */
  printf("nd range kernel1 (%d %s)\n", st, clErrorString(st));

  end = clCreateUserEvent(context, &st);
  printf("create user event (%d)\n", st);

  callback_data* user_data = (callback_data*)malloc(sizeof(callback_data));

  printf("c_v %p\n", (void*)c_v);

  user_data->queue = &queue;
  user_data->buf_c = &buf_c;
  user_data->c_v = c_v;
  user_data->size = size;
  user_data->end = &end;
  user_data->nested_callbacks = use_nested_callbacks;
  use_data->blocking = use_blocking;

  if (use_callbacks){
    st = clSetEventCallback(ev_kernel, CL_COMPLETE, callback_kernel_fn, user_data);
    printf("set event callback (%d)\n", st);
  }
  /* printf("finish queue\n"); */
  /* clFinish(queue); */
  /* printf("finished queue\n"); */

  if (use_callbacks){
    printf("waiting for events\n");
    /* /\* cl_event events[] = {ev_kernel}; *\/ */
    cl_event events[] = {end};
    clWaitForEvents(1, events); // ev_kernel);
    printf("waited for events\n");
  }else{
    printf("about to read the c buffer\n");
    st = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, buf_c, use_blocking, 0,
                             size * sizeof(int), c_v, 0, NULL, NULL);
    printf("read buffer c_v - buf_c (%d)\n", st);
  }

  free(user_data);
  // ...
  #define THRESHOLD 0
  // check
  printf("about to check (first: %d)\n", c_v[0]);
  for (size_t i=0; i<size; i++){
    if (abs(c_v[i] - (a_v[i] + b_v[i])) > THRESHOLD){
      printf("Wrong checking: a_v[%ld] = %d, b_v[%ld] = %d, c_v[%ld] = %d\n", i, a_v[i], i, b_v[i], i, c_v[i]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
  // ...

}
```

My problems are related to racings and freezes.

Three questions:

1. If I use `use_callbacks = 1`, `use_blocking = CL_FALSE` and `use_nested_callbacks = 0` **is there any potencial racing when checking the contents of C?** (maybe the `clEnqueueReadBuffer` from `callback_kernel_fn` hasn't finished when we are checking C in `main`). Also, if I use `use_callbacks = 0` and `use_blocking = CL_FALSE` **is there any potencial racing when checking the contents of C?** (all in the same function `main`).
2. Also, **what is the difference in asynchronous behavior between using callbacks and using `clFinish`**? with `clFinish` I need to provide the `queue`, but can I still modify the queue from a callback to be able to continue the execution? **I would like use cases**.
3. **Why using Intel Xeon (CPU and Phi) the process hangs (freezes)** when doing `clEnqueueReadBuffer` with `use_blocking = CL_TRUE` only if done in the `callback_kernel_fn` but not if done in the `main`? (so, using `use_callbacks = 1` for the first, or `use_callbacks = 0` for the second case. It does not happen when using e.g. NVIDIA or AMD GPU.

Comment: Note that complex code on the callback functions is not allowed in the OpenCL specification, and some functions are specifically disallowed: 

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetEventCallback.html

In particular, clEnqueueReadBuffer cannot be called from your callback function.
The main reason is that the OpenCL implementation may have a single scheduling thread, which is calling the callback. If you perform a blocking operation inside the callback, you are blocking the only thread that can execute that operation.

Comment: @Ruyk And how would you do that async behavior dynamically? With the callbacks I understand the behavior, but how would you do it if it is not with callbacks? (can you modify the queue dynamically?)

Comment: @user3819881 You can signal other threads inside the callback.

Comment: @user3819881 What do you mean by async behaviour? Non-blocking enqueue operations are asynchronous w.r.t the user thread. They are enqueued into the OpenCL queue, hence they execute one after the other (unless an out-of-order queue is created). clFinish simply blocks the caller thread until all operations in the queue have finished. You can continue to enqueue work on the queue, including from different threads, but it is up to you to synchronize the OpenCL operations with the caller thread. You can, for example, set up a user event that sets an atomic that your thread is monitoring.